# Facing "Error: unable to get local issuer certificate Code: UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY" when trying to update CLI. How to overcome this one

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, cli

To set up SFDX , first I did install CLI and when I tried updating the same, I'm facing this issue. Can anyone please help me out.

Comment: Try https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_install_cli_firewall.htm

Answer (score 0):

Likely you have a proxy or something (like zscaler) in the way of the TLS connection. Either work out the nodej SSL config or simply bypass by running:
set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0

Answer (score 0):

It is likely because you are using a VPN.

So temporarily disable your VPN/firewall then do the sf update command.